# WriteLine with a class

Tags: c#, .net, list, class

I'm making a SchoolApp program to learn about C# and I have this main function that I'm trying to make work:

```
namespace SchoolApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            School sch = new School("Local School");
            sch.AddStudent(new Student { Name = "James", Age = 22 }); // this function
            sch.AddStudent(new Student { Name = "Jane", Age = 23 });
            Console.WriteLine(sch); // this implementation
        }
    }
}
```

School class:

```
namespace SchoolApp
{
    class School
    {
        public string name;

        public School()
        {
        }

        public School(string the_name)
        {
            name = the_name;
        }

        public void AddStudent(Student student)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Student class:
namespace SchoolApp

```
{
    class Student
    {
        public int Age;
        public string Name;
        public Student()
        {
            Age = 0;
            Name = "NONAME";
        }

        public string _name 
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Name;
            }
            set
            {
                Name = value;
            }
        }
        public int _age
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Age;
            }
            set
            {
                Age = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm new to C# and I am pretty lost as to how I should make the AddStudent and how to work with the WriteLine to write the class. The output should be along these lines:

School: Local School
James, 22
Jane, 23

Someone suggested using List<> I hit the same problem of not knowing enough about it.

EDIT: Thank you all for your extremely fast answers. I got it working and will now commense reading the answers in depth so I don't have to ask related questions again!

Answer (score 6):

`Console.WriteLine(t)` perform implicit conversion of t to string. So you need to override `ToString()` for all your classes or create string from your class explicitly.

Example:

```
class School
    {
        public string name;
        List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();

        ...
        public override string ToString()
        {
           var stringValue = name;
           foreach(var student in Students)
           {
              stringValue += student.ToString();
           }
           return stringValue;
        }
    }

class Student
{
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
   ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Age);
    }

}
```

Comment: How would I go about avorriding it?
I tried it and I just got hammerd down with errors.

Comment: Error 1 'SchoolApp.School.ToString()': not all code paths return a value 
Here:  public override string ToString()

Answer (score 4):

In your `School` class it looks like you want to have a private list of Students.  List is simple, it takes in a generic type, in your case `Student` and you can add and remove items to/from it.

In your `School` class use:

```
 private List<Student> students;
```

And in your AddStudent code you could simply use:

```
students.Add(student);  // student is the variable being passed in and students is the list.  NOTE: You will have to make sure students is intalized to a new List of Student.  students = new List<Student>();
```

Take a look at the following links.  MSDN is the proper documentation, but the dotnetperls is good for simple stuff like this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/3wcytfd1.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-add

Answer (score 2):

```
class School
{
    public string name;
    private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    public School()
    {
    }

    public School(string the_name)
    {
        name = the_name;
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        students.Add(student);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(name);
        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(student.ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}

class Student
{
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Student : " + Name + ", " + Age;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now to study this in depth. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> Someone suggested using `List<>` I hit the same problem of not knowing enough about it.

Yes, the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class is appropriate for this situation. It has an .Add method which allows you to add objects to it. And then you could loop through the elements of this list (using a `foreach` statement) and then print each element details to the console using Console.WriteLine method.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `List<Student>` which needs to be a member of `School` , added with a loop (`foreach`) in your main method to print them out, you should also look at the following :

- should your classes be public ? the main program may not be in the same namespace.
- Have you considered using auto-properties with getters and setters ?
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

  ```
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  ```
- your naming conventions, 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/618ayhy6(v=vs.100).aspx

All of the above because you said you are new, so I thought might as well give you a few pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to add a `School` with a corresponding `Students`

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class School : Student
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
List<School> school = new List<School>();
school.Add(new School() { SchoolName = "USA", StudentName = "har", Age = 25 });
school.Add(new School() { SchoolName = "USM", StudentName = "japz", Age = 25 });
foreach (var item in school)
{
    Console.WriteLine("School Name: {0} Name: {1} Age: {2} ", item.SchoolName, item.StudentName, item.Age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method "WriteStudent" to the Console class and accept student as a parameter. Inside the method you could use `Console.Write("School: " +objParameter.Name)`

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 basic options:

1. to add a "school" attribute (variable) to each student
2. to add a "students list" attribute to each school.

if you prefer the second method:

you need to add a new variable to school class:

```
 List<Student> student_list = new List<Student>();
```

and in order to Add student, define:

```
 public void AddStudent(Student student)
 {
 student_list.Add(student);
 }
```

also note that if you want the print to be in a specific order, you have to add ToString() method in both student and school classes.

hope it helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a container to store the instances of the `Student` class in the `School` class. Then, in your `AddStudent` method, you simply add the student to your collection using the method exposed by the List class itself:

```
class School
{
    public string name;
    private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    // ...

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    { 
        students.Add(student);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) is a reference to the `List` class.

As for the output, you can write a function in the `School` class itself to output the students:

```
public void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
    foreach (Student s in students)
        Console.WriteLine(s.Name + ", " + s.Age);
}
```

And use it in your `Main` simply like:

```
sch.Print();
```