# How can I create a User class and register new users?

Tags: c#, class, object

I'm trying to create a class called User that can register new Users and store them in a list. Currently, I just want to be able to use the RegisterUser object. I have a C# book and have tried understanding it, but it's not clicking. Any help or hints in the right direction are very much appreciated.

```
namespace UserClass {

    /// <summary>
    /// The user class
    /// <summary>

    public class User {
        public string userName;
        public string password;
        public string address;
        public int contactNumber;


        public static RegisterUser(string username, string pass, string add, int contact) {
            User newUser = new User();

            newUser.userName = username;
            newUser.password = pass;
            newUser.address = add;
            newUser.contactNumber = contact;

            WriteLine(newUser);
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you said you wanted a list of users but you haven't written one yet.. Have a think about would be a suitable place to put it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO , what do you mean with clicking ? Currently you have defined a class and a static operator for initialize it , but you need a program where use this class, it could be a Console program o even one with an UI

Comment: 1. `RegisterUser` doesn't have a return type, so it will produce a compiler error. Since you're not trying to return anything, I would change it to `public static void RegisterUser`. 2. I don't see `using static System.Console;`, and I don't see a custom `WriteLine` method so that doesn't seem likely to work. 3. The default `.ToString()` method of a class will print it's name, so if `WriteLine` were `Console.WriteLine`, I would expect to see "UserClass.User" printed in the console after calling `RegisterUser`.

Comment: @Llama I'm not sure I would encourage a newbie to use `static`

Comment: @Caius And I didn't. The book OP is following seemingly encouraged it.

Comment: [Question that covers problem 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467965/method-must-have-a-return-type-unity-3d) from my comment above. [Question that covers problem 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052761/writeline-with-a-class).

Comment: Your code is invalid. Is it simply the C# isn't "clicking" for you?

Comment: Note that `add` is a reserved keyword. Change the variables to `addr` or something different,

Comment: @JohnAlexiou AFAIK It's *contextual* but not *reserved* like `case`, `new`, `private` etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - yeah I realized the compiler is smarter than me.

Comment: Can someone explain me about the RegisterUser thing? And why it has a “;” at the end? It doesn’t look to have a return type so it cant be a function, then what is it? It’s the fist time I’m seeing something similar, and I cant find info on the internet. Or is it just a mistake he made?

Answer (score 3):

A few issues with your code:

1. `WriteLine` is incorrect unless you've created that method

I think you're looking for `Console.WriteLine(...)` which you can
use after adding `using System;` however even that would be
incorrect.

I assume you are looking to print the values of fields in
the `User` class which in that case, either override `.ToString`
(bad idea) or access and print them separately.

2. `RegisterUser` has no return type

It could be `void` -> `public static void RegisterUser(string username, string pass, string add, int contact)` indicating that nothing is returned.

However, common convention and expectation would be that the new `User` object is returned so that the caller can know what the final state of the operation was ->

3. You have a rogue `;` at the end of the implementation of `RegisterUser(...)`

You need to remove it to make your code compile.

4. You actually have no variables anywhere, which would allow you to create a collection

You need to add your users to something like a `List<User>`, which would be encapsulated internally in another class perhaps called `UserManager`. This allows you to expose behaviour but hide the implementation, as well as adhering to [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

You could then expose the collection of users if you needed to, in a clear way, using a [`ReadOnlyCollection<User>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-5.0).

This would show consumers that they would probably have to call a method (`RegisterUser`) to be able to add to the collection of users as `ReadOnlyCollection<User>` prevents modification, and not just do `users.Add(...)` & bypass your registration logic.

In this case, `RegisterUser` would also not have the `static` keyword, as it would need access to the instance field - your collection of users - and it won't be able to do that as a static method.

5. Your namespace is extremely specific to your `User` class

It's technically okay but namespaces are used to organise classes & control scope. I would rename it to something more related to your domain, as opposed to something bound to your class name (`UserClass`).

6. Arguments for `RegisterUser`

I would also cut down on the number of arguments to `RegisterUser`, take in a `User` object and then enforce all fields being set using the constructor for `User`.

This would turn it into a *monadic method*, making the code more readable, easier to test later on and makes you keep a conscious tab on how many "things" the method is responsible for.

Something like the below should work:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class User
    {
        public string UserName;
        public string Password;
        public string Address;
        public int ContactNumber;

        public User(string username, string pass, string add, int contact)
        {
            UserName = username;
            Password = pass;
            Address = add;
            ContactNumber = contact;
        }
    }

    public class UserManager
    {
        private readonly List<User> _users = new List<User>();

        public ReadOnlyCollection<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return _users.AsReadOnly();
        }

        public User RegisterUser(User newUser)
        {
            // process user, modify fields, add etc.
            
            _users.Add(newUser);

            return newUser;
        }
    }

    public static class UserOutput
    {
        public static void WriteUserToConsole(User user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{user.UserName}, {user.Password}, {user.Address}, {user.ContactNumber}");
        }
    }
}
```

```
var userManager = new UserManager();

var userToBeRegistered = new User("A", "B", "C", 0);
var createdUser = userManager.RegisterUser(userToBeRegistered);
UserOutput.WriteUserToConsole(createdUser);

var allUsers = userManager.GetUsers();

foreach (var user in allUsers)
    UserOutput.WriteUserToConsole(user);
```

Comment: you are pointing out his bugs, not answering his question. Perhaps show some code

Comment: @JSGarcia I wanted to give an initial answer and then update it, I was going to and have now added supporting code :)

Comment: It's good but I'd say be wary of "doing people's homework for them. I accept that this is a tough one because really a more or less complete code example is required to convery the concepts you wish to teach here, but perhaps labor the teaching more and the coding less/let the user do the coding. It's difficult in the context of SO because this one requires a lot of back and forth (and as such it's not well suited to the SO Q&A style) - something they should really be having with their tutor.. :D

Comment: @CaiusJard I agree but I think the answer should introduce them to a few new concepts, which they may not be aware of otherwise - you're right tho :)

Answer (score 0):

you are nearly there

```
public class User 
{
    public string userName;
    public string password;
    public string address;
    public int contactNumber;
}

// Separate Class to create and store the users
public class UserController
{
    // List to store your Users
    public List<User> UserList;

    // Constuctor instatiates UserList
    public UserController()
    {
        UserList = new List<User>();
    }

    public void RegisterUser(string username, string pass, string add, int contact) {
        User newUser = new User();

        newUser.userName = username;
        newUser.password = pass;
        newUser.address = add;
        newUser.contactNumber = contact;

        // Adding the user to the UserList
        UserList.Add(newUser);

        // Show the userName of the new User in Console
        Console.WriteLine(newUser.userName);
    }

}
```

you can now Register users with your method in the new separate class. They will be stored in the UserList that you can access freely from outside of the class.

usage:

```
//get a UserController to start working
UserController controller = new UserController();

// call to RegisterUser 
controller.RegisterUser("bob", "1234", "mystreet 1", 42);
```

Comment: `WriteLine` still seems like it will be a compiler error unless OP has code they're not showing.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I changed my response to acomodate your sugestion

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yes, unless users have friends, teams they lead etc.. Be careful not to run too quickly into slamming fellow professionals based on the most loose/incomplete of specs..

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are close. See if the following points will help.

1. `RegisterUser` is a function/method with no purpose as it is missing a return type specification. Here you have two design options:

   1. Create a new user and return a variable referencing this user.

      ```
      static User RegisterUser( ... )
      {
          newUser = new User();
          ...
          return newUser;
      }
      ```
   2. Create a new user and store the user internally to a list. This means the function specification *must have `void` in its return type*.

      ```
      static List<User> userList = new List<User>();

      static void RegisterUser( ... )
      {
          newUser = new User();
          ...
          userList.Add(newUser);
      }
      ```
2. You can specify the *required* information to define a user by declaring a constructor which assigns this information when a new User object is created. For example, if the `username` and `password` are the only required field then

   1. Create a constructor accepting these two values

      ```
       public class User
       {
           ...
           public User(string userName, string password)
           {
               this.userName = userName;
               this.password = password;
           }
       }
      ```
   2. Change the fields on *readonly* such that they cannot be modified at a later time.

      ```
       public class User
       {
           public readonly string userName;
           public readonly string password;
           public string address;
           public int contactNumber;
           ...
       }
      ```
3. There is no defined way to display the information for each user on the console and so a call to `Console.WriteLine(user)` will only display the user type (default behavior of C#). To add this functionality to a class, override the `ToString()` method.

   ```
   public class User
   {
       ...
       public override string ToString()
       {
           return $"User = {userName}, Address = {address}, Contact = {contactNumber}";
       }
   }
   ```

   Now in the main program when you loop through the registered users, you can simply invoke `Console.WriteLine()` on each one to show on the screen the information.

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       User.RegisterUser("aaa", "abc1", "100 east", 55500);
       User.RegisterUser("xyz", "uvw5", "120 north", 55501);

       foreach (var user in User.registededUsers)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(user);
       }
   }
   ```
4. it is common practice to hide fields behind properties. In this case it would be useful not to expose the list of registered users outside of the class as `List<User>` because it will allow the addition of new items in the list *without requiring to call the `RegisterUser()` function*. To disallow this behavior remove the `public` from the `registededUsers` field and add a property called `RegisteredUsers` expose this field as a `IReadOnlyList<User>`

   ```
   public class User
   {
       ...
       static List<User> registededUsers = new List<User>();
       public static IReadOnlyList<User> RegisteredUsers { get => registededUsers.AsReadOnly(); }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterUserVM userVM)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
            AppUser user = new AppUser
            {
                Name = userVM.Name,
                Email = userVM.Email,
                Surname = userVM.Surname,
                UserName = userVM.Username
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user,userVM.Password);
            if (!result.Succeeded) 
            {
                foreach (var item in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "ur username or password invalid");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    enter code here
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginUserVM userVM)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid) return View();
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userVM.UsernameorEmail);
            if(user == null)
            {
                user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userVM.UsernameorEmail);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "ur username or password invalid");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, userVM.Password, userVM.IsPersistance, true);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "ur username or password invalid");
                return View();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
```

Comment: this code is used to validate a user and not to create one

Comment: this code is used to validate a user and not to create one